# Wheel Joint 2D motor and gravity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gravity

I'm creating a 2D car game (driving hills). I use Wheel Joint 2D to implement car suspension and wheel rotation. It works quite well on flat terrain.

Now I would like to add a gravity influence to a motor speed. Unfortunately gravity works only when I deactivate `useMotor`. Otherwise I just stand on the side of a hill and don't move.

Is there any way to sum gravity and motor velocities?

Comment: Please explain more clearly, I do not understand the problem. Motor adds momentum to a joint, meaning, rotational force. Gravity adds directional force to bodies. How would you like them to interact, and how do they behave instead?

Comment: Simply I want motor to move wheels and gravity to 'pull' car down if it's up on a hill. Right now, when motor is on, gravity won't pull car down. It still stays on a hill side (like on a hand brake).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here's a sample project with motor script attached.

Now it works like a charm!

http://www.thegamecontriver.com/2014/11/hill-climb-racing-like-2d-car-physics-2.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is reduce the friction between the wheels and the ground. Experiment with the physics material you set on the wheels and/or the ground.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Nope. I don't want wheels to slip. I want them to rotate downwards after I release forward button.

Comment: Oh. Yes, you have to turn the motor off if you want the wheels to rotate backwards due to gravity.

Comment: Still not. Imagine I slow down in 20% each second. Climbing steep mountain will result in slowing down till 0, then, after turning motor off, I'll run backward very fast. It looks completely unnatural.

Comment: Try changing the gravity multiplier on your car rigid-body (also the wheels and where necessary).